# Getting message Set::setps: Kpr[x,y] in the part assignment is not a symbol

Tags: matrix, warning-messages

I use a loop to create a set of matrixes `Subscript[k[x, y], i]`, depending on variables `x, y`. Then I create a large matrix

```
Kpr[x_, y_] = ConstantArray[0, {12, 12}];
```

In this matrix, using a loop, I write the values of matrices from the set in a similar way:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 12, i++, 
  Kpr[x, y][[1, 1]] = 
    Kpr[x, y][[1, 1]] + Subscript[k[x, y], i][[1, 1]]]`.
```

From this I get the message

> Set::setps: Kpr[x,y] in the part assignment is not a symbol.

This means that no matrix elements are assigned.

If I set a matrix

```
Kpr = ConstantArray[0, {12, 12}];
```

without dependency on `x` and `y` and assign the elements of the matrix like so:

```
 For[i = 1, i <= 12, i++, 
   Kpr[[1, 1]] = Kpr[[1, 1]] + Subscript[k[x, y], i][[1, 1]]]`.
```

matrix formation will occurs. But it is important for me to get a matrix with a dependency  on `x` and `y`.

**Code**

```
For[i = 1, i <= 12, i++, 
  Subscript[k[x_, y_], i] = 
    {{x, y, 5 + i, 5}, {5, 4, 2 i, 0}, {x + i, 3, 5, y}, {4, 5, 3, 2}}]

Kpr[x_, y_] = ConstantArray[0, {12, 12}];
For[i = 1, i <= 12, i++, 
  Kpr[x, y][[1, 1]] = Kpr[x, y][[1, 1]] + Subscript[k[x, y], i][[1, 1]]]
```

Comment: I can't follow your code's logic unfortunately. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?.

Comment: Oh, sorry if you don't understand. I'm trying to build a large matrix from the elements of small matrices and keep the dependency on x,y. In fact, the elements of small matrices are distributed throughout the large matrix, if this is more clear. The problem is assigning an element of one matrix to an element of another matrix while preserving the representation of the matrix as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me give you what I think is a piece of good advice. Subscripted variables may look pretty in a notebook but they can cause difficulties when you try use them in programs. You can take this as the wisdom of experience or see the note at the end of this answer to find out why this is so.

I will replace the subscripted variable `k` with the *indexed* variable `k`, which will be much more tractable. Like so:

```
Clear[k]
Do[k[i][x_, y_] = 
  {{x, y, 5 + i, 5}, {5, 4, 2 i, 0}, {x + i, 3, 5, y}, {4, 5, 3, 2}}, {i, 12}];
```

This produces 12 functions, `k[1], ..., k[12]`, which can be used to populate the diagonal of the 12 × 12 function `Kpr`.

```
Kpr[x_, y_] = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {12, 12}], {i_, i_} :> k[i][x, y]];
```

This defines a `Kpr` matrix that returns a 4 × 4 k-matrix when queried on the diagonal and zero when queried off the diagonal. Examples:

```
Kpr[u, v][[3, 3]]
```

> ```
> {{u, v, 8, 5}, {5, 4, 6, 0}, {3 + u, 3, 5, v}, {4, 5, 3, 2}}
> ```

```
Kpr[u, v][[3, 5]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Note: When one uses subscripted variables, the values are stored as down-values of `Subscript`. Therefore, expressions like `Clear` using the variable's name have no effect on them. Indexed variables, however, are stored as sub-values of the named variable and things like `Clear` work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful!